# How to override 'data-testid' in the 'findByTestId function from Cypress Testing Library

Tags: cypress, testing-library, cypress-testing-library

Most of my existing codebase uses a 'id' only in few places 'data-testId' attribute present.
tried this code

```js
import { configure } from '@testing-library/cypress';

configure({ testIdAttribute: ['data-testId','id'] });
```

But, still its not working.

Is there any way to use 'id' value in any of the testing-library functions.

My HTML code is something like:

```html
<div class="some random class name" id="userprofile-open" role="button">SB</div>
```

I want click that element with this code:

```js
cy.findByTestId("userprofile-open", { timeout: 120000 }).click();
```

Comment: Pls elaborate - you want to change the properties on the elements or to be able to select them? Would be helpful if you share an HTML code of such element=

Comment: my HTML code is something like:
<div class="some random class name" id="userprofile-open" role="button">SB</div>
Then , I want click that element with below code:
 cy.findByTestId("userprofile-open", { timeout: 120000 }).click();

Comment: Good that information is better - for further questions - you need to include such things if you want people to help you. We cant help if we cant see the problem and the code. Also you can edit your question to include it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can configure testing-library with an array of ids, ref [API configuration](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-configuration),

```js
import { configure } from '@testing-library/cypress'
configure({ testIdAttribute: 'id' })
```

But even this fails. Instead you have to use the Cypress command to change the attribute name (only one name is allowed).

```js
cy.configureCypressTestingLibrary({ testIdAttribute: 'id' })
```

---

To use either/or attribute name you can change the attribute name on the fly, wrapping it in a custom command (based on [Custom Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-custom-queries))

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('findByTestIdOrId', (idToFind) => {
  
  let result;

  const { queryHelpers } = require('@testing-library/dom');
  let queryAllByTestId = queryHelpers.queryAllByAttribute.bind(null, 'data-testId');

  result = queryAllByTestId(Cypress.$('body')[0], idToFind)
  if (result.length) return result;

  queryAllByTestId = queryHelpers.queryAllByAttribute.bind(null, 'id');
  result = queryAllByTestId(Cypress.$('body')[0], idToFind);
  if (result.length) return result;

  throw `Unable to find an element by: [data-test-id="${idToFind}"] or [id="${idToFind}"]`

})

cy.findByTestIdOrId('my-id')
  .should('have.attr', 'id', 'my-id')  
// passes and logs "expected <div#my-id> to have attribute id with the value my-id"
```

**Note** this custom command works only for synchronous DOM.

---

If you need to have Cypress retry ***and*** search for either/or attribute, don't use testing-library in the custom command.

Instead use Cypress `.should()` to enable retry

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('findByTestIdOrId', (selector, idToFind) => {
  cy.get(selector)
    .should('satisfy', $els => {
      const attrs = [...$els].reduce((acc, el) => {
        const id = el.id || el.getAttribute('data-test-id')  // either/or attribute
        if (id) {
          acc.push(id)
        }
        return acc
      }, [])
      return attrs.some(attr => attr === idToFind); // retries when false
    })
    .first();                                       // may be more than one
})

cy.findByTestIdOrId('div', 'my-id')
  .should('have.attr', 'id', 'my-id')  
// passes and logs "expected <div#my-id> to have attribute id with the value my-id"
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual cypress way - which has an inherent check on the element visibility and existence as well as included retries for a period of time is using [cy.get()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get#Get-in-within)

If you want to select element using property like data-id you need this sintax: `cy.get('[propertyName="propertyValue"]')`

If you want select an element by CSS selector you just pass CSS selector like this:
`cy.get('#id')`

Comment: yes I know cy.get(#id) works. But, to maintain the uniform locating mechanism across 
 the framework we want use Cypress Testing Library methods only(like findByRole, findByText, etc...)
Refer: https://testing-library.com/docs/cypress-testing-library/intro

Comment: I only found this git repo with examples. May be it will help you. https://github.com/testing-library/cypress-testing-library/blob/main/cypress/integration/find.spec.js 

I haven`t used that library